# IIS 10 - prevent USERS to access directory but allow IIS_IUSRS

Tags: permissions, iis-10

I'm running IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019.
I want to share a directory only to certain network users, so they should be able to read/write content, while other users should be blocket.
On the other side, the directory must be server by a public domain.

My need: I want to publish files with "hashed" name (eg.: db27c4c90228520338f2314752e7e6217e1f24a.jpg), so that only people having the direct url can see them; other people on the network must not see them.

How can I properly configure permissions?

Comment: What you need is a web app similar to OneDrive. Unfortunately IIS itself does not have any built-in feature for that. Don't mess up the default permissions, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/default-permissions-user-rights or your IIS will stop working.

Comment: What if I create a shared directory available only to those users who need to upload files (and forbidden to other users) and another directory server by IIS... then I sync the contents with an external script?

Comment: You might consider using an existing solution like FileVista